# бинд активной текстуры

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

У меня есть две текстуры, которые рисуются в разных позициях (условно в x1 y1 первая текстура и x2 y2 и вторая), но метод рисовки рисует только ту текстуру, которая была первой передана в метод. В общем, не меняет предыдущую текстуру на другую

```
public static void draw(String path, int x, int y, ByteBuffer buffer, BufferedImage image) {
        if(buffer == null){
            System.err.println("buffer is null");
            buffer = TextureLoader.ByteBufferEncoder(path);
        }
        if(image == null) {
            System.err.println("image is null");
            image = TextureLoader.BufferedImageEncoder(path);
        }
        //считывает размеры экрана
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        glOrtho(0, dim.height, dim.width, 0, -1.0, 1.0);

        //параметры
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        
        //верхний левый угол
        glTexCoord2i(0, 0);
        glVertex2i(x, y);
        //нижний левый угол
        glTexCoord2i(0, 1);
        glVertex2i(0 + x, image.getWidth() * 2 + y);
        //нижний правый угол
        glTexCoord2i(1, 1);
        glVertex2i(image.getHeight() + x, image.getWidth() * 2 + y);
        //верхний правый угол
        glTexCoord2i(1, 0);
        glVertex2i(image.getHeight() + x, 0 + y);

        //glVertex2i Задает вершины
        //glTexCoord2i Задает текущие координаты текстуры

        glEnd();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Как решается сей проблема? Половину гугла перерыл, ничего особо не нашел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так, по итогу вышел вот такой чуть измененный код

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL13.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL13.glTexCoord2i;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL13.glActiveTexture;

public class TextureDrawing {
    public static void draw(String path, int x, int y, ByteBuffer buffer, BufferedImage image) {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        //если при вызове не приходят буфферы, то сам декодирует их исходя из пути
        if(buffer == null){
            System.err.println("buffer is null");
            buffer = TextureLoader.ByteBufferEncoder(path);
        }
        if(image == null) {
            System.err.println("image is null");
            image = TextureLoader.BufferedImageEncoder(path);
        }
        //параметры, бинд текстур, и прочее
        int textureID = glGenTextures();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

        //очистка и рисовка квада на экране
        //РИСОВКА ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО ИДЕТ МЕЖДУ glBegin(); и glEnd();
        //разрешение рисовки/наложения текстур
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        //верхний левый угол
        glTexCoord2i(0, 0);
        glVertex2i(x, y);
        //нижний левый угол
        glTexCoord2i(0, 1);
        glVertex2i(0 + x, image.getWidth() * 2 + y);
        //нижний правый угол
        glTexCoord2i(1, 1);
        glVertex2i(image.getHeight() + x, image.getWidth() * 2 + y);
        //верхний правый угол
        glTexCoord2i(1, 0);
        glVertex2i(image.getHeight() + x, 0 + y);

        //glVertex2i Задает вершины
        //glTexCoord2i Задает текущие координаты текстуры

        glEnd();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }
}
```

и вот такой кусочек в основном классе, из за неправильной инициализации камеры оно не работало

```
    public void init(){
        //инициализирует библиотеку
        glfwInit();
        System.out.println("'glfw' has been initialized");
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();
        if(glfwWindow == NULL){
            //если окна не существует - создаст
            glfwWindow = glfwCreateWindow(this.width, this.height, this.title, NULL, NULL);
        }
        else {
            //при попытке создания окна возникла ошибка - сообщит
            System.err.println("error at create glfwWindow");
        }
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(glfwWindow);
        //vsync
        glfwSwapInterval(1);
        //настройка отображения
        glfwShowWindow(glfwWindow);
        //подключает инструменты библиотеки
        GL.createCapabilities();

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glOrtho(0, dim.height, dim.width, 0, -1.0, 1.0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    }
```

Comment: upd:  int textureID = glGenTextures();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID) в данном коде вроде не особо нужен, у меня без него все нормально